# Can I "optimize" a query involving a text column?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

If I have this 400M rows table:

```
create table my_table
( id int,
  filled tinyint,
  content text not null
) engine=myisam
```

can I prevent the extra access of content (due to column type text) with:

```
select id,if(filled,content,'') from my_table
```

(filled is 0 or 1)?

Or if content can be null, would

```
select id,ifnull(content,'') from my_table
```

be better (still in term of performance since the null overhead would then occur)?

Comment: The two queries do not do the same thing, to start with. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to prevent the extra access of content (due to column type text) if it is not filled

Comment: "extra access of content" --- in the first query you select everything. "Is there anoter one better than these?" --- given you haven't indexed them - every query would involve a full scan.

Comment: Correct. and in the table scan, I don't want content to cause an extra disk access when it is not filled

Comment: since the question refers to a table scan, I removed the query having a where

Comment: relevant: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/103370/37113

Comment: "Normally a record is a continuous stream of bytes in the .MYD file. This includes TEXT and BLOB columns" I thought TEXT was stored off-row thus required an extra access to be retrieved

Comment: It's unlikely that your use of MyISAM is deliberate. Is it? If not, perhaps it's time to upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is imprecise.  Might a row have `filled = 1` and `content = 'some text'`?

If yes, then the `IF(filled, content, '')` makes sense.

If no, then get rid of `filled` and simply set `content` to `''`.  The cost of accessing an empty string for `content` is tiny.

How big is `content` typically?  If is usually only hundreds of characters, the performance difference is small.

Don't use MyISAM, switch to InnoDB.

Do you have a lot of `DELETEs` or `UPDATEs`?  If so, the .MYD file of MyISAM may be fragmented.  This implies that `content` may be scattered around the disk.  If you have no updates or deletes, then `content` is "right there", hence virtually free to access.

In contrast, InnoDB *sometimes* puts `TEXT` and `BLOB` "off-record".

But, which is better or worse?  The off-record (in some situations) versus the fragmentation (in some situations).

Are you fetching just one row?  Or lots of such rows?  This is another area where MyISAM and InnoDB are implemented quite differently.  MyISAM needs to step over `content` to get to the "next" row.  (I won't go into a lengthy discussion of *where* the "next" row is likely to be.)

Bottom line:  Don't worry about optimizing, but *do* change to InnoDB (for a lot of reasons).

**Where is the "next" row likely to be?**

MyISAM...  Rows are added to the .MYD in the order of inserts.  But, after updates or deletes, new/changed rows tend to fill in the gaps first, leaving appending to the file as a last resort.

InnoDB...  Rows are in a B+Tree ordered by the `PRIMARY KEY`.  The BTree is blocked with 16KB blocks.  You have a `TEXT` column, so it gets more complex...

For "small" TEXT columns, several rows will fit into 16KB.  If, say, `content` is 1KB strings, up to about 15 rows will be put in a block.  If they are much bigger, then `content` will be stored "off-record".

The rows in a block are essentially all equidistant from each other.  (The big effort is loading the block into cache and locating the block.)

The "next" (or "previous") block is just a disk access away -- see the "+" in "B+Tree".

When a block overflows, it is "split" into two blocks, some rows go into each.  The new block is allocated somewhere, rarely adjacent.

With SSDs, all blocks are "equidistant" from each other.  With HDD, rotational delays and arm motion complicate the timing of which block might be "closer" than some other block.

Comment: Accepted. BTW where can I read some info about _where_ the "next" row is likely to be ?

Comment: @guigoz - I added to my answer.  If you want more details, start a new question, and narrow it down to which Engine you want to talk about.